# Jasper Report: Remaining Data is moved to the next page and some empty space exists in the previous page for a List(Datasource) in Detail Band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have Jasper Report with Header, Detail and Footer. In detail I'm using a List(Datasource) where I have 4 inner Lists inside the Main-List. I'm using Print-when-expression and Remove_Line_When_Blank is true for Inner-List's. When 2 Inner-List's are printed, 3rd Inner-List is skipped and 4th Inner-List is moved to next page where there is a empty space after the 1st and 2nd list in the previous page and the empty space is sufficient of the 4th list. Is there anything to do as the 4th List to print in the place of empty space. Please check the attached Image for reference. [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X78dN.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the referenced image didn't make it / is not currently showing I'm talking a blind guess and say "Remove Line When Blank" (`isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"`) in the Appearance tab of the Properties of some of the Lists might do the thing you want.

Comment: I've already used isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true", but no change